# Simulating race using c# multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a mission to simulate people running.

One is doing 2 steps every 300 seconds,
and the second is doing x steps in y seconds.

I don't want a full solution but only to know wich mechanism would be the right for this and why.

p.s - At first I thought of using timers but for the second races it's not good enough.

Comment: Re your tags - Be clear about your constraints etc, multi-threading is a bad choice here.

Comment: What you've stated can be solved by a deterministic calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a formula to calculate the distance travelled for each runner at a certain time:

```
runner[n].StepsTraveled = secondsPassed * (runner[n].StepsPerSecond);
```

Regardless of refresh interval you'll always have correct distance they traveled. You can use any resolution timer or even refresh every button click.

And you don't need multithreading either.

If multithreading is a must your each thread can have this structure:

```
var runner = this runner for the thread;
while(running) 
{
  Thread.Sleep(runner.Seconds * 1000); // convert to milliseconds
  runner.StepsTraveled += runner.Steps;  
}
```

And you can use the same thread code for each runner all you need to change is which `runner` object they'll use.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an assignment so he MUST use multi-threading. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek I added another suggestion for that :)

Comment: That's better now. :) +1

Comment: No, not better. Threading confuses real-time and simulation-time.

Comment: @Pragmateek - there is no clue of an 'assignment' here, you're making things up.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I confess, this is guess work: 1) the task is not what I expect in 99.9% of real-life use-cases, but this is possible if the company is Nike or Garmin 2) the OP does not seem proficient in multi-threading 3) two persons running is a good academic assignment to help students grasp the multi-threading concepts. :)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution in you situation is to pass a **delegate** to the **Timer** (C# has several multi-threaded timers\workers implementations).
I have already made similar thing - arkanoid game on Windows Forms, check it out:
https://github.com/ElliotCoder/GDIPlus_Arkanoid

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multithreading, simply use 2 **timers**: `300 / 2` s and `y / x` seconds. Or, if you really want, create 2 threads and in first **wait** for 300 and then perform 2 steps (or evenly, 150 s and 1 step) and in second **wait** for `x / y` and perform 1 step.

Comment: Timers uses multithreading: typically each tick the timer runs the user code on a **threadpool thread**. (Not a reason to downvote anyway :()

Answer (score 0):

you could use a **background worker**, with the "progress changed" event its easy to update the GUI to display the "runners"

Answer (score 0):

I would create my own `Race` (or `World`) class that gets all objects to move (maybe because they implement `IMoveable`). Then this class has also a method `IncrementTime()` (and maybe `IncrementTime(TimeSpan timeToElaps)`). Whenever this method is called it gets from every `IMoveable` the `Speed` and changes its `Position` accordingly to the passed time and the speed of the object.

By using this approach you are independent of the real-world time and you can run your simulation also faster or slower if desired. Nevertheless you need within your application some kind of `Timer` that triggers your `IncrementTime()` regulary, but it is quite easy possible to influence the real-time it needs to run through.

Comment: This is an elegant solution but not sure this is what is expected for a first assignment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the building blocks you need:

- to represent the race of one runner a method; to avoid having two different methods you can factorize the common code and pass a parameter for the speed
- to represent the concurrent execution of the two runners races you need to execute each method in the context of a new `System.Threading.Thread`
- to represent the passing of time you'll use the `Thread.Sleep` method
- to represent the wait of the main thread (say that it represents the referee) you'll use the `Thread.Join` method

Hope I've missed nothing...